# Android: MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin

It's really frustrating that every time Android Studio suggests to upgrade your Gradle plugin -and you do- you end with a lot of problems.

I was advised to upgrade Gradle plugin from `8.2.2` to `8.3`, and after that app stopped building.

The first thing I tried, to no avail, was `git reset --hard HEAD` to revert all modified config files to their respective previous state, but the same error still happens.

My app already uses `minSdkVersion 26` in build.gradle, but as long as I can understand from the error stack-trace the problem could be happening in `Apache POI` and `Apache log4j` jar libraries, but I don't have a clue on how to deal with them, as they are apparently not part of my project, or at least not directly added by me.

These are the relevant parts of my error stack-trace:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26): Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/util/ServiceLoaderUtil;callServiceLoader(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Z)Ljava/lang/Iterable;","sources":[{"file":"/Users/diego/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/9a05842052291609defaad6cb51ec0bd/transformed/jetified-log4j-api-2.21.1.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26): Lorg/apache/poi/poifs/nio/CleanerUtil;lambda$null$0(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)Ljava/lang/Throwable;","sources":[{"file":"/Users/diego/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/52819773c62ede0f70c689b16da3da7e/transformed/jetified-poi-5.2.5.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}
```

And more:

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Services:mergeExtDexDebugAndroidTest'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':Services:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform poi-5.2.5.jar (org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.5) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=24, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: /Users/diego/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/52819773c62ede0f70c689b16da3da7e/transformed/jetified-poi-5.2.5.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
           Increase the minSdkVersion to 26 or above.

   > Failed to transform log4j-api-2.21.1.jar (org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.21.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=24, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: /Users/diego/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/9a05842052291609defaad6cb51ec0bd/transformed/jetified-log4j-api-2.21.1.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
           Increase the minSdkVersion to 26 or above.
```

This is my main module (app) build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id('dagger.hilt.android.plugin')
    id('com.android.application')
    id('kotlin-android')
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
    id('kotlin-kapt')
}

android {
    compileSdk 34
    def code
    Properties versionProps = new Properties()
    def versionPropsFile = file('version.properties')
    if (versionPropsFile.exists())
        versionProps.load(new FileInputStream(versionPropsFile))
    code = (versionProps['VERSION_CODE'] ?: "0").toInteger()+ 1
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            pickFirsts += ['META-INF/LICENSE.txt']
            excludes += ['META-INF/NOTICE.md', 'META-INF/LICENSE.md', 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST', 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES', 'META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties']
        }
    }
    versionProps['VERSION_CODE'] = code.toString()
    versionProps.store(versionPropsFile.newWriter(), null)
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.xxx.xxx'
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 34
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode code
        versionName "5.0." + code
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17

        }
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        }
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    bundle {
        density {
            // Different APKs are generated for devices with different screen densities; true by default.
            enableSplit true
        }
        abi {
            // Different APKs are generated for devices with different CPU architectures; true by default.
            enableSplit true
        }
        language {
            // This is disabled so that the App Bundle does NOT split the APK for each language.
            // We're gonna use the same APK for all languages.
            enableSplit false
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.all { output ->
                    project.ext { appName = 'xxx' }
                    def newName = 'xxx.apk'
                    outputFileName = new File("./build/", newName)
                }
            }
        }
        /*debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.all { output ->
                    project.ext { appName = 'xxx' }
                    def newName = 'xxx.apk'
                    outputFileName = new File("./build/", newName)
                }
            }
        }*/
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    dataBinding{
        enabled = true
    }
    lint {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    namespace 'com.xxx.xxx'
}

dependencies {
    api files('libs/achartengine-1.2.0.jar')
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:16.3.0'
    //mail API 16
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.7'
    implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.7'
    //apache commons text
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-text', version: '1.11.0'
    //Youtube player
    implementation 'com.thefinestartist:ytpa:1.2.1'
    //Font Selector List Preference
    //api 'com.vanniktech:vntfontlistpreference:1.0.0'
    //Rate my app
    implementation 'com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:1.0.1'
    //Support
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.8.2'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.2'
    runtimeOnly('androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2')
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.6.2'
    //Annotation
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.1'
    //AlertDialog
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@aar'
    //glide animated gifs
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0'
    implementation 'androidx.window:window:1.3.0-alpha02'
    ksp 'com.github.bumptech.glide:ksp:4.16.0'
    //circular score
    implementation 'com.wssholmes.stark:circular-score:0.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
    implementation 'com.github.mejdi14:Flat-Dialog-Android:1.0.5'
    //picasso
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    //Stream
    implementation 'com.annimon:stream:1.2.2'
    //Multidex
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    //Hilt
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.50'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.7'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.50'
    kapt('org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.9.0')
    kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.1.0'
    //modelmapper
    implementation 'org.modelmapper:modelmapper:3.2.0'
    //volley
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    //openai
    implementation 'com.aallam.openai:openai-client:3.7.0'
    implementation('io.ktor:ktor-client-android:2.3.8')
    implementation platform('com.aallam.openai:openai-client-bom:3.7.0')
    //glide animated gifs
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0'
    //audio visualizer
    implementation('io.github.gautamchibde:audiovisualizer:2.2.7')
    //jsoup
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.17.2'
    //moshi
    implementation('com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.15.1')
    ksp('com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.15.1')
    ksp('com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.15.1')

    implementation project(':DTO')
    implementation project(':Common')
    implementation project(':Background')
    implementation project(':Core')
    implementation project(':Services')
}
```

I don't know if it might be relevant, but before upgrading Gradle, I upgraded Android Studio to `Iguana | 2023.2.1`

How can I make my app build again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that the build is failing when executing the `:Services:mergeExtDexDebugAndroidTest` task, then most likely the `build.gradle` of the `Services` module does have a `minSdkVersion` lower than 26.

Please make sure that all the other modules have minSdk greater than (or equal to) 26.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Lino. You were completely right, all the other modules were using minSdk 24, so I changed to minSdk 26 and that error dissapeared. Unluckily now I'm having "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space", but as I was trying and trying maybe in the middle of something whatever got wrong, but this should be for another post, and I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: I just would like to add that, as per my research, the culprit was Android Studio Iguana. I was using Android Studio Hedgehog, and my app was building just fine, but after updating it stopped working. Once more I come to the conclusion that trying to be up-to-date with the development environment is not a good idea, because most of the times I update Android Studio I end encountering problems. Now I unistalled Iguana and went back to Hedgehog and everything's working fine again.

Comment: mmm strange... I tested your scenario on Android Studio Iguana... no idea

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Lino, if I'm not wrong I first updated to Iguana, and then I was adviced to migrate Gradle Plugin from 8.2.2 to 8.3, and after all this process the build process started to fail. But don't worry, now that I have a working environment with Hedgehog and everythings backed up, I'll update to Iguana and try again. I'll let you know.